# FirebaseError: Function addDoc() called with invalid data

Tags: firebase, vue.js, google-cloud-firestore, vuex

I'm trying to create user collection in Firebase using addDoc function. When I run it in component it works but when I dispatch it from Vuex displays that error

vuex.esm-browser.js?5502:1057 Uncaught (in promise) FirebaseError: Function addDoc() called with invalid data. Unsupported field value: a function (found in field username.dispatch in document users/ULLwEmHPaYcRnaN7EFgW)

firebase config.js

```js
import { initializeApp } from "@firebase/app";
import { getAuth } from "firebase/auth";
import { getFirestore, collection, getDocs, addDoc } from "firebase/firestore";

const firebaseConfig = {
  apiKey: process.env.VUE_APP_FIREBASE_API_KEY,
  authDomain: process.env.VUE_APP_FIREBASE_AUTH_DOMAIN,
  projectId: process.env.VUE_APP_FIREBASE_PROJECT_ID,
  storageBucket: process.env.VUE_APP_FIREBASE_STORAGE_BUCKET,
  messagingSenderId: process.env.VUE_APP_FIREBASE_MESSAGING_SENDER_ID,
  appId: process.env.VUE_APP_FIREBASE_APP_ID,
  measurementId: process.env.VUE_APP_FIREBASE_MEASUREMENT_ID,
};

initializeApp(firebaseConfig);

const db = getFirestore();
const users = collection(db, "users");
const auth = getAuth();

export { db, auth, getDocs, users, addDoc };
```

store index.js

```js
import { createStore } from "vuex";
import { auth, addDoc, users } from "../config/firebase";

  actions: {
    async createUser(username, email) {
      await addDoc(users, {
        username: username,
        email: email,
      });
    },
```

createUser Function in component

```js
    const userData = reactive({
      email: "",
      userName: "",
    });

    const createUserWithEmailAndPassword = async () => {
      store.dispatch("createUser", userData.email, userData.userName);
      console.log("userData :>> ", userData);
    };
```

Comment: If you voted up my answer below and it solved your problem please consider to mark my answer as best one. Near my answer under votes arrows you have check mark(will change color to green).

Answer (score 1):

The action function has to have it's first argument as context, then arguments.

**Like below.**

```js
async createUser(context, username, email) {
      await addDoc(users, {
        username: username,
        email: email,
      });
    },
```

The error you're getting is that the field `username` in `addDoc()` function is an object and not a string.

If you enable persistence in firestore you no need vuex. It's just a small tip. Vuex might be only needed if you for example want to store some temporary data like shop cart and you don't want to save them until the user will actually buy them. I use vuex if I want to popup some snack on the user's screen with information like "Success! Data: XXXXXXXXXX was saved.".